# TransactionManager and datasource in spring boot - spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactionmanager

I wanted to access the Transaction Manager and datasource in my configuration in spring boot application. I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` artifact.

Is it possible to just autowire in the config and get its access?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get access to the transaction manager with:

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

For the `DataSource`, out-of-the-box with the starter you chose you will get the `tomcat-jdbc` datasource:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-configure-datasource

You can just inject that like this:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Make sure you use the JDBC `DataSource` type (`javax.sql.DataSource`), and not a specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks leeor, code in general works worked, but IntelliJ complains for autowiring saying  "No Beans of 'DataSource' type found. And same for transaction manager

Comment: Hmm, what version of intellij? newer versions have better support for spring-boot. You might also be able to make that go away by adding spring facets to your module under `project structure`.

Comment: It is 15.0.1 ultimate, and I tried adding spring facets but it is still there. It might be because I may not doing it properly.

Comment: I think v2016 added more boot support http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/02/intellij-idea-16-spring-boot-and-kotlin-rc/ not sure that would fix it but could.